# calling a global function with a class method with the same declaration

Tags: c++, gcc, word-wrap

I would like to wrap a C library within a C++ class. For my C++ class I also would like to have the same declaration used by these C function: is it possible to do that?

If for example I have the case below how would it be possible to distinguish the C-function from the C++ one? I would like to call the C one off course.

```
 extern int my_foo( int val ); //

 class MyClass{
    public:
    int my_foo( int val ){
           // what to write here to use
           // the C functions?
           // If I call my_foo(val) it will call
           // the class function not the global one
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use the [scope resolution operator `::`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator):

```
int my_foo( int val ){
    // Call the global function 'my_foo'
    return ::my_foo(val);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use **Qualified name lookup**

```
::my_foo(val);
```

This tells the compiler you want to call the global function and not the local function.

Answer (score 7):

```
::my_foo(val);
```

that should do it.