# Qt with close(int) function?

Tags: qt

I'm making usb sniff program with Qt Creator.

Qt has already bool close(); function;

but I want use fcntl.h for open(), unistd.h for close() function

same name of close function, so I don't know i dont know what to do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to call `close()` as defined in unistd.h instead of `QWidget::close()`, in which case this is a C++ question rather than a Qt one. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149922/calling-a-global-function-with-a-class-method-with-the-same-declaration) will help you. The solution is to use the scope resolution operator like so:

```
::close(); // calls the global function
```