# Call function with same name as method

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I'm trying to define a template class that has some operations on a type.
The method ToString should be implemented to call the ToString in the namespace of whatever type the Tools template class has been instantiated with.

```
namespace X
{
    class SomeType
    {
    };

    std::wstring ToString(SomeType)
    {
       // ...
    }
}

template<class T>
class Tools
{
    static auto ToString(T& t)
    {
        return ToString(t);
    }
}
```

I get an error in the Tools implementation of ToString. The compiler tries to recursively call the method ToString again instead of calling the ToString in namespace X.

I can't use  X::ToString as that will fail when I try to instantiate the Tools class with a type from namespace Y. Eg, if I use:

```
namespace Y
{
    class SomeOtherType
    {
    };

    std::wstring ToString(SomeOtherType)
    {
       // ...
    }
}

Y::SomeOtherType someOtherType;
auto s = Tools<Y::SomeOtherType>::ToString(someOtherType); // Would fail as SomeOtherType isn't in namespace X.
```

Is it possible to make this work?

I'm using VS 2015 Update 3. A solutions that work for that is preferred.

Related: [calling a global function with a class method with the same declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149922/calling-a-global-function-with-a-class-method-with-the-same-declaration)

Comment: I don't see why `X::ToString()` won't work can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Galik: He means he wants `namespaceof(T)::ToString()`. i.e. it could also be `Y::ToString()` or `Z::ToString()` or something else. So just writing `X::ToString()` is not right.

Comment: If I understand correct (not certain) it seems you want `X::ToString();` to be able to be called with different parameter types (`X::SomeType` & `Y::SomeType`). For that you will need to make it a template function.

Comment: Are you sure you want `Tools` to be a class? What state does it hold? Are you merely working around a lack of namespace templates? It seems like you're deliberately fighting the language in more than a few ways; can you try to avoid that? (At least make `ToString` `static`)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. You're right Tools doesn't hold any state and I made a mistake in not adding 'static'. I've got a set of functions for dealing with enums such as serializing them etc. In my real code Tools is called Enum and takes an enum as an arg. The purpose of the class is just to group all of the functions together so that I can write Enum<SomeEnumXXX>:: and intellisense will tell me what all the functions are so that I don't have to remember the names of the functions for working on enums.

Comment: @Galik I've updated the question with an example of it not working with X::

Comment: @ScottLangham: That's reasonable. I would not agree with making design decisions based on what some IDE is going to do, but until we get namespace templates that seems okay from a code perspective anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I might have a solution. Add an intermediate function that is outside the class with a different name, that then calls with the correct name.

Add

```
namespace ImplementationDetail
{
    template< class T >
    auto ToStringHelper(T& t)
    {
        return ToString(t);
    }
}

template<class T>
class Tools
{
    auto ToString(T& t)
    {
        return ImplementationDetail::ToStringHelper(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems reasonable. As an aside, this is one of the reasons I don't subscribe to the "make everything a free function" religion; a member function of `T` here would have been extraordinarily simple and clear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Yes I agree. I forgot to explain that the T types are actually enums to which I can't add methods.

Comment: Good stuff then :)

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly use

```
 return ::X::ToString(t);
```

to reference the function in the `X` namespace, irrespective of which namespace the reference comes from.

Comment: Hmm, yes, but calling a function in the X namespace irrespective of which namespace it's in isn't much use when the function is in a Y namespace.